# from all listed files and subdirectories change a directory

Tags: c++, c++17, working-directory

I'm currently writing a program that lists all the files and subdirectories in the current directory.

I'm struggling with the ability to change directory, so after listing all directories and subdirectories I need to be able to change directory. In my code I have `fs::is_directory(myPath)` which tells me if this file is a directory or not, and if it is I want to point in my path to it and then print the files from inside. I can do it even by using `parent_path` but I have no idea how to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path myPath("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\things");

    cout << "your path is : " << myPath << endl;
    cout << "name of this directory is : "<< myPath.filename() << endl;
    cout << fs::is_directory(myPath) << endl;                        
    cout << myPath.parent_path() << endl;                                             

    for(auto file : fs::directory_iterator(myPath)) {
        cout << file << " " << fs::is_directory(file) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with recursion. Create `listDirectory(std::string && path)` function with a loop, which you have, but add a different behavior for a file and for a directory.
Here is a pseudo-code:

```
void listDirectory(const std::string &path) {
    for (auto file : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
        if (fs::is_directory(file)) {
            listDirectory(file);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need in rvalue reference in this function. Moreover thie code doesn't compile because the `file` variable is a lvalue.